# No bass from the speakers

Tags: sound, preferences

In Ubuntu 11.10 no bass sound at all when try to play mp3 or 2channels audio. I have 5.1/6 channels speakers.

When I test speakers from the sound preference it works perfectly fine and then I try to play any MP3 there is no bass only the speakers work, I play 5.1 movies it plays fine bass sounds good.

Also tried to to some changes as instructed with `deamon.conf` file but no go...

When I turn my speakers on play speakers only mode it plays the bass but sound quality is not good compared to normal playing. I have a Creative 5.1 vx ca0160 sound card.

In Windows also had the same problem unless I do bass redirection crossover frequency so is there any kinda software package or any kinda changes i can make in system file so that my speaker bass works fine or any thing who can let me change the bass redirection crossover  frequency?

Answer (score 2):

To get bass, you can edit the settings using `alsamixer` from the terminal. Sometimes by default, certain channels are muted as denoted by `MM`. Simply press the **M** key on your keyboard.

Comment: none of the channels are muted....

Comment: the subwoofer plays like a normal speaker no bass like 6channels but i have 5.1...

Comment: That save me a lot of time :) thx

Answer (score 1):

Configure your player for channels, If you are using Totem, got0 **edit-preferences-Audio** and change the Audio Output type to 5.1,

Answer (score -1):

If neither of the other responses work I would recommend going to the motherboard manufacturer's website, look up your motherboard and search for Linux sound drivers.

-Best of Luck

Comment: the subwoofer plays like a normal speaker no bass like 6channels but i have 5.1...